# Proving $\arg()=\arg()+\arg()$?

Tags: complex-analysis

algebraic demonstration $\arg()=\arg()+\arg()$

Proving algebraic demonstration $\arg()=\arg()+\arg()$

Comment: Do you know the definition of arg? Hint: write $z$ and $w$ in exponential form.

Comment: What have you tried?